# Parse data from text file into comma delimited values

Tags: sql, excel, csv, vbscript, sybase

I have thousands of records like below in a line spaced text file.  I am trying to create a delineated file of some sort to import in SQL.  Be it by script, function, even excel I just can't get it.

```
RECORD #:  #####
NAME:  Tim
DOB:  01/01/2012    
SEX:  male 
DATE:  07/19/2012   


NOTES IN PARAGRAPH FORM


END OF RECORD
RECORD #:  #####
NAME:  Tim
DOB:  01/01/2012    
SEX:  male 
DATE:  07/19/2012   


NOTES IN PARAGRAPH FORM


END OF RECORD
```

Desired output:

```
RECORD #:  #####,NAME:  Tim,DOB:  01/01/2012,SEX:  male,DATE:  07/19/2012,NOTES IN PARAGRAPH FORM
RECORD #:  #####,NAME:  Tim,DOB:  01/01/2012,SEX:  male,DATE:  07/19/2012,NOTES IN PARAGRAPH FORM
```

Comment: is this simply replace end-of-line with comma? or do you need to transform any of the labels/values

Comment: The desired output format isn't suitable for further sql processing. Would you consider a more standard .csv output format? Could you add a sample for the "PARAGRAPH FORM"?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional The notes in paragraph form probably gets screwed up then. Can't Oracle Loader do it in one go? I was looking at BCP format files.

Comment: What is the target database platform?

Comment: This place rocks.  Sybase.  Need to create a table that has columns record#, name, dob, sex, date of record, NOTES. sample of notes belows

Comment: **NOTES** This 45 year old female presents today for initial evaluation of  wart-like growths.  Patient has a new lesion on her right thumb. She is afraid this is a wart. She also has a wart on her right knee and right inner thigh.  She also wants a growth on her chest "zapped off".

Answer (score 1):

A plan:

1. Use .**ReadAll**() to load your input file into memory (fallback: line by line reading, "END OF RECORD" triggers processing of record)
2. Use **Split**(sAll, "END OF RECORD") to get an array of records (strings). For Each sRecord
3. Use **Split**(sRecord, EOL, **6**) to get 5 'one line fields' and 1 text/notes/memo field that may contain EOLs or not
4. Use one **RegExp** ("\w+\s*#?:\s*(.+)") (fallback: specialized RegExps) to cut the data from the 'one line fields', trim leading/trailing whitespace from the 6th
5. Transform fields as needed: string data should be quoted, EOLs and quotes in the 6th should (probably) be excaped, using a standard date format (yyyy-mm-dd) may avoid problems later
6. .**WriteLine** **Join**(aFields, sSep) to output.csv
7. Describe the format of your output.csv in a **schema.ini** file (choose easy/save column names!)
8. Use the import facility of your DBMS or ADO to **import** the .csv into the database

Feel free to ask for details.